# problema al enviar parámetros por el método post laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel

Hola estoy recien con laravel me instale la version 5.5 y he creado mi formulario de pruebra
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][3]][3]

luego llamo a la vista en el controlador
el problema es el siguiente cuando hago submit me sale lo siguiente: The page has expíred due to inactivity. please refresh the page and try again
si se cargada sele una excecion de dice asi:Environment & details:

```
protected function methodNotAllowed(array $others)
{
    throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException($others);
}
```

GET Data empty
POST Data empty
Files empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error aparece porque no has incluido el token en el formulario, para lo cual debes agregar un código similar a este:

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" >
```

También lo puedes hacer con laravel collective.

Comment: o puede hacer esto tambien **{{ csrf_field() }}**

Comment: Gracias funciono

Answer (score 0):

Mirando el codigo que has puesto, me parece que tu error está a la hora de declarar la ruta. Prueba poniendo:

```
Route::post('/login', 'MenuController@index')->name('login');
```

Y en tu codigo html cambia

```
form action="{{ url('login') }}"
```

Por esto

```
form action="{{ route('login') }}"
```

espero k resuelvas

Comment: ya lo hice y siempre me dice la mismo